# No devices are booted. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native

When I run react-native run-ios, I get this error.

The following build commands failed:

> CompileC
>   /Users/huanghongxia/work/react-native/appProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bits.o
>   /Users/huanghongxia/work/react-native/appProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party/folly-2016.09.26.00/folly/Bits.cpp
>   normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       (1 failure)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appProject.app
>       No devices are booted.
>       Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appProject.app/Info.plist
>       Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I have tried these steps:

- Delete the node_modules folder `- rm -rf node_modules` && `npm install`
- Reset packager cache `- rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* or node_modules/react-`
  native/packager/packager.sh `--reset-cache`
- Clear watchman watches `- watchman watch-del-all`
- Recreate the project from scratch

But it doesn't work.

Comment: react native version?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.45.1

Comment: Have to try to remove the current app in your simulator, or even better to Reset All in your simulator. Also delete the "build" folder in "ios" and try "react-native run-ios" again

Comment: The error info of 'Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist ' doesn't show any more, by downloading the boost , and extract and copy into appProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party

But I have got another problems: BUILD SUCCEEDED, BUT No devices are booted.


** BUILD SUCCEEDED **


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appProject.app
No devices are booted.
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.appProject
No devices are booted.

Comment: please upgrade to the latest react native 1) npm install react-native-git-upgrade 2) react-native-git-upgrade  ..run both the commands simultaneously from project root dir..

Comment: Could you please tell me which version should I upgrade.
react-native: 0.45.1 is the latest version.

Comment: This issue has fixed, Tks.
solution:
1. downloading the boost , and extract and copy into appProject/node_modules/react-native/third-party
2. delete the "build" folder in "ios" and try "react-native run-ios" again

Comment: It's also very important that the project isn't under any parent folders that have a space in their name. Simple thing but cost me about 8 hours today